# How to get the actual qmake build destination within the project file?

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake

I'm trying to determine the build directory in the qmake project file, but failed in all my experiments so far :-(

At first I had a very plain `foo.pro` as QtCreator generates it for a plain Qt5 gui app with a few source files. Then I added an `EXTRA_BINFILES` list with some data files. They must be copied in the same directory as the executable `foo`. Without the copy stuff, it looks like this:

```
QT       += core gui xml webkitwidgets widgets

TARGET = foo
TEMPLATE = app

EXTRA_BINFILES += \
    foobar.png \
    baz.png 

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    # ...

HEADERS  += \
    # ...

FORMS    += \
    # ...
```

When I build that, I get the `foo` executable (or `foo.exe` if you want). Mostly straightforward so far. Now I want to copy the `EXTRA_BINFILES` alongside this executable. The open question is how to get the destination directory. My best idea so far is adding this:

```
for(FILE, EXTRA_BINFILES) {
    QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote($${QMAKE_COPY} $$shell_path($${PWD}/$${FILE}) $$shell_path($${OUT_PWD})$$escape_expand(\n\t))
}
```

This uses the `OUT_PWD` variable, which automatically points to where the Makefile is generated. This is nice for some scenarios. However, I have to deal with two different scenarios:

- Directly compiling from within QtCreator with mostly out-of-the-box build configs. It creates a new `build-foo-desktop-release` directory, creates the Makefile there and builds the executable there. In this scenario, everything works fine.
- Building from command-line with `qmake -makefile /my/projects/foo/foo.pro` and `make` in a temporary fresh build directory. This way it creates the Makefile in directly in that build directory but compiles the executable into a `release` subdirectory`. This obviously breaks my copy code.

For some reasons, it is not an option to get rid of one of those scenarios. I have to deal with both of them within the same project file. It is also not an option to make very technical/tricky things in the project file. It has to remain mostly as 'straightforward' as it is. Overriding some of qmake's own variables in the `qmake` command-line call is also probably not an option. This is because of the broader context, which is too extensive to explain here.

Is there an option to get the correct path in both scenarios? Something like `OUT_PWD` but for the executable itself?

Unfortunately, `DESTDIR` is empty (and as mentioned, it is not an option to forcefully set it). `DESTDIR_TARGET` is empty as well (otherwise I could combine it with `dirname`, which would be barely non-tricky enough).

Any hints?

Comment: You know your build destination. Your target is going to be built in the current directory. So you can use $PWD variable to copy the files near the executable.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub_dir = $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_
sub_dir ~= s,^$$re_escape($$PWD),,
PROJECT_BUILD_TREE = $$clean_path($$OUT_PWD)
PROJECT_BUILD_TREE ~= s,$$re_escape($$sub_dir)$,,
```

Comment: Thank you for coding that! But unfortunately this also does not work here (at least in my wine-driven mingw toolchain for building windows EXEs - i'm not sure if that matters here). It copies the files alongside the Makefile, as my first experiment did as well. And it is very near to my threshhold of pain regarding the trickyness (either above or below that threshhold; I'm not sure ^^).